# How many sequences have only one caracter (A/B) as a difference

Tags: python

I have a list of sequences for example:
The problem is the optimization part, I have a list of million sequence

```
List= ["ASHAOSHZO", "BSHZOSHZO", "ASHBOSHZO","EIBDEDIED", "EIBDEDIEA",  "IJZUHDIZUDB", "JLZOAUUIGIZ"]
```

I want to return only sequences that have only one character (A/B) as difference (swipe ) in the same position.

in this example I would have

```
res = [("ASHAOSHZO", "BSHZOSHZO"), ("ASHAOSHZO", "ASHBOSHZO")]
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: Why `pandas` and `numpy` tags?

Comment: well mainly because my list is 1 million sequence and therefore a normal python code would not work, I need a more optimized choice

Answer (score 2):

This is not a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) or [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) question, you can achieve this in pure python with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest, combinations

out = [(a,b) for a,b in combinations(List, r=2)
       if sum(c1!=c2 for c1, c2 in zip_longest(a,b)) == 1]
```

Output:

```
[('EIBDEDIED', 'EIBDEDIEA'), ('ASHZOSHZO', 'BSHZOSHZO')]
```

If you want to limit the characters to A/B:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, combinations

chars = {'A', 'B'}

out = [(a,b) for a,b in combinations(List, r=2)
       if sum({c1, c2} <= chars and c1!=c2
              for c1, c2 in zip_longest(a,b)) == 1]
```

Output:

```
[('ASHZOSHZO', 'BSHZOSHZO')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the thing is I have huge list and with this code for example there is no way It will work, I have to figure out a quicker way, for instance a break after sorting the list ?

Comment: Can you give a more complex example in your question? Do you want to get the first match only? In this case, using a generator in place of the list comprehension might be the solution. You would need to give more details, optimization is only possible if you know exactly how the data looks like.

Comment: do u mean generate a file containing 500.000 sequence and put it into the question ? not sure how am I supposed to do so

Comment: You could already start with an example in which there would be more than one pair in the output. Also, are the sequences all similar or can you cluster them by a given property?

Comment: I tried to update the list, also we can group data by length but this might also take alot of time (got clusters of 200.000 sequence with same length, we also can sort them and use break